# Elapsed time format HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, formatting, gregorian-calendar

It's a simple problem but I'm not getting it to work.

I'm incrementing a variable each second and setting it in a GregorianCalendar in miliseconds.

And I'm using this format `HH:mmss` to present the elpased time.

The problem is that the hour starts showing 01 instead of 00. For instance, after 1 minute and 35 seconds what is shown is: `01:01:35` instead of `00:01:35`.

Where could be the problem?

There is the important code:

```
GregorianCalendar timeIntervalDone = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1")); //initially I didn't have the TimeZone set, but no difference
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeIntervalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

public String getTimeIntervalDoneAsString() {
    timeIntervalDone.setTimeInMillis(mTimeIntervalDone); //mTimeIntervalDone is the counter: 3seccond -> mTimeIntervalDone = 3000
    return dateTimeIntervalFormat.format(timeIntervalDone.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it:

```
GregorianCalendar timeIntervalDone = new GregorianCalendar(); 
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeIntervalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateTimeIntervalFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: Drawback: It will only work for time intervals smaller than one day (24 hours).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you set the time zone to GMT-1, but the output is utc. Please try it without that time zone and it should work.

Comment: Without the time zone the result is the same.

Comment: Oh sorry,  I didn't scroll to the end to see that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a hack, trying to use a date-time moment class (`GregorianCalendar`) to represent a span of time. Plus your format is ambiguous, looking like a time-of-day rather than a duration.

## ISO 8601

An alternative is to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard way of describing a duration: [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the year-month-day portion from hour-minute-second portion.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework in Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The old classes have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

The java.time framework is inspired by the highly-successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, and explained in the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The java.time framework does use ISO 8601 as its defaults, this otherwise excellent set of classes lacks a class to represent an entire period of years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds. Instead it breaks the concept into two. The [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class handles years-months-days while the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class handles hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now ();
Instant later = now.plusSeconds ( 60 + 35 ); // One minute and 35 seconds later.

Duration duration = Duration.between ( now , later );
String output = duration.toString ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

> output: PT1M35S